Loading style 'example.css' in a specific element made by elementor
I'm looking for a solution to load a style sheet 'assets/styles/example.css' for an element made with elementor only when this element is visible on the page. This element is a custom template with an ID of 302.
I don't want to use elementor's "Custom CSS" functions because I'll need to deploy updates to this file on several website later.
I have access to my file functions.php.
ID of post is 302. I tried the following conditions: is_page(), is_singular() but they were not recognized.
define('KS_CSS_PATH', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/');

if (! function_exists('load_example_style')):
  function load_example_style() {
    // if (is_page(302)) {
    wp_enqueue_style('ks-example-css', KS_CSS_PATH . 'example.css');
    // }
  }
endif;
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_example_style', 21);

Actually, this is loading in every page. Appreciate any help possible!

To enqueue custom CSS for a specific Elementor element only, use the Elementor hook instead of wp_enqueue_scripts.
Elementor's elementor/frontend/widget/before_render action hook can enqueue the CSS only when a specific widget is rendered or available on the page.
Try the following code:
function gs_enqueue_custom_css_for_elementor_element( $element ) {
    wp_register_style( 'custom-elementor-heading-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-elementor-heading.css', array(), '1.0.0' );
    // check if heading element adds in the page
    if ( 'heading' === $element->get_name() ) { //replace 'heading' with your widget name
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-elementor-heading-css');
    }
}
add_action( 'elementor/frontend/widget/before_render', 'gs_enqueue_custom_css_for_elementor_element' );

The given code will enqueue the CSS file custom-element or-heading.css if, the page has the heading elementor widget

Updated code:
The updated code will help to enqueue the CSS based on the Template Id in the selected pages.
function gs_enqueue_custom_css_for_elementor_element( $element ) {
    wp_register_style( 'ks-example-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/example.css', array(), '1.0.0' );
    if(is_page(100803)){ // replace with the Id of page where you are adding the template element.
        if ( 'template' === $element->get_name() ) {
            // Get the settings for the element
            $settings = $element->get_settings_for_display();
            // Get the template ID from the settings
            if ( !empty( $settings['template_id'] ) ) {
                $template_id = $settings['template_id'];
                
                if($template_id == 1047){ // replace with template element Id.
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'ks-example-css');
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'elementor/frontend/widget/before_render', 'gs_enqueue_custom_css_for_elementor_element' );

Note: Add the above code to the Child Theme's functions.php
The code has been tested and it works as required.

How to find the name of my element. I don't know if you understood me well. What I want is to add the style but to an element, which is among other things a container, not a widget. This element is created in "Templates>Saved Templates" => https://imgur.com/a/yqrlo0X. It has the id "302" and slug "example".

Give more information, your comment is not very clear.  Send the screenshot of the element you need to add the style.

I made you a screen of my template => https://imgur.com/a/pzzR66R
So what I'd like to happen is that when my container or section is displayed in a page, the css styles I've written in my 'example.css' file are loaded. This can be inline or in head, I don't mind.
What interests me is that I can modify these styles over time directly via ftp.
If you can see in this example, it's a section with the id '1047' and the slug 'example.

Check the updated code. It should be helpful to enqueue the CSS based on the template element ID.  I will wait for your reply.
